# Swift execute code after return, unbelievable

Tags: swift

I created a tableview and there is a toggle in a cell, I click the toggle there will be a function in the cell's protocol, and in the implement of the function I have a logic like this:
[image]

The print function after the return is executed! can't believe this anybody know why? Or this is a bug of apple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning in your screenshot tells you exactly what's happening:

> Expression following ‘return’ is treated as an argument of a ‘return’.

When return is being called it sometimes takes an expression, which in this case is a function.

If you don't want the print statement to be part of the return, you could add a `;` to the end of return

Comment: In Swift, return statement in a Void function can return only one specific value Void().
(An instance of Void, which is equivalent as the empty tuple ().)
And the return type of print is Void, which means it returns Void().


Thus, the result of calling print("what?") can be a return value of Void function as you see.

Thanks answer from here:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671904#671904021